# Question about Riverpod.. Show list of pdf files in a list view

Tags: android, flutter, state-management, riverpod

**This is my provider:** *(I believe the problem is here)*

```
final fileListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<BookProvider, List>((ref) {

  return BookProvider();
});


class BookProvider extends StateNotifier<List>{
  BookProvider() : super([]);

  late String directory;
  List file = [];

  void listOfFiles() async {
    directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    file = io.Directory(directory).listSync();
  }
}
```

**And this my widget class:** *(Consumer here)*

```
class BookListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const BookListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(

      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, ref, _) {

          /// listen to provider variable.
          final file = ref.watch(fileListProvider);

          return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                  maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                  childAspectRatio: 2 / 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20),

              itemCount: file.length,

              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                String name = basename(file[index].toString());
                return BookListItem(bookName: name);
              }
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to show all pdf files from the application folder into a list view. I think the problem is that the provider doesn't return the desired list! I'm new to Riverpod so I would really appreciate the help. Thanks

I also want to know what should I do if I wanted to split my provider into an individual class, because I can't make `fileListProvider` as a static when it's a global variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `listOfFiles` in the constructor to initialize the state. Then in `listOfFiles` you should set `state` to a new value to change the state.

```dart
class BookProvider extends StateNotifier<List>{
  BookProvider() : super([]) {
    listOfFiles();
  }

  late String directory;

  void listOfFiles() async {
    directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    state = io.Directory(directory).listSync();
  }
}
```

Regarding your second question about splitting the provider into an individual class, you can create a separate file for your provider and import it in your widget file. Since `fileListProvider` is a global variable, you can access it from anywhere when you import the file it's defined in.